# Have button in view trigger console application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have the following console application that connects to a WCF endpoint:

```
namespace TestSendMail
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             SendMailClient client = new SendMailClient("BasicHttpBinding_ISendMail");               
             client.Send("Test", "something@mail.com", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "name", "John Snow" }});
         }    
    }
}
```

What would an MVC view that had a button (that would trigger the console application) and a controller that handles it look like?

Both the MVC project and the Console project are part of the same solution.

Comment: You would just create an object of class program and call the main function on buttons click event. Also you would need to make it public both class and main method.

Comment: Thank you for your comment fsacer. I won't be able to try it out right now so I will get back to you later when I have.

Comment: Why do you call the console application at all? Just add the relevant code to your MVC controller.

Comment: What have you tried? What are you having trouble with? Have you googled "c# call console application" and "asp.net button click handler"?

Comment: @Robert
Thank you for your comments, the issue has been resolved.

Comment: @sirdank Thank you, the issue is resolved.

Comment: @FadiY An upvote would be appreciated.

Comment: @fsacer Sorry, I don't have enough points. If you make it an answer I can check it as the right one. And then I will have enough points to give you an upvote :)

Comment: @FadiY I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just create an object of class program and call the main function on buttons click event. Also you would need to make it public both class and main method.